# Rails can't find POST path for modal form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, modal-dialog

I've created a form that works great when it is not showing in a modal window. When I plug it into the modal, suddenly POST is looking for the path in the wrong place.

I've scoured questions on SO and read through the RAILS guides and API docs for routing and controllers, and can't find the answer. I'm tempted to blame ":remote => true" in the form - it seems like there may be something I need to add to the controller - but I can't find what.

Here are the routes from the controller's **rake routes:**

```
messages POST /messages(.:format)     messages#create
new_message GET  /messages/new(.:format) messages#new
```

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :messages, only: [:new, :create]
```

**Controller:**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
      if @message.valid?
        NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
        redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Thanks! Your message was sent."
        return  
      else
        render :new
      end
  end
end
```

**Form tag** (the form displays and works beautifully except for sending):

```
<%= form_for(:message, :remote => true) do |form| %>
```

From the **Nav:**

```
<%= link_to('Contact', new_message_path, :class => 'contact', :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => '#myModal')  %>
```

**POST error** from the log:

```
Started POST "/messages/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-12 14:33:43 -0800
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/messages/new"):
```

**POST as it happens in the working, non-modal version:**

```
Started POST "/messages" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-12 14:27:50 -0800
Processing by MessagesController#create as HTML
```

Log file entry from click on "Contact":

```
Started GET "/messages/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-12 14:33:37 -0800
Processing by MessagesController#new as JS
  Rendered messages/_form.erb (5.1ms)
  Rendered messages/_new.erb (7.7ms)
  Rendered messages/new.js.erb (10.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 14.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

What is the right thing to do to get the POST working?

Comment: Could you please include the log entries starting from the request when you click the 'Contact' link? It has been a while since I worked with Rails' UJS handler, but this might be helpful.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the click from "Contact".

Comment: Thank you. How does your `new.js.erb` look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `form_for` tag is expecting a new `Message` object to be passed to it. You've already instantiated a `@message` variable in the `new` action of your controller, so simply pass it to your `form_for` tag:

```
<%= form_for(@message, :remote => true) do |form| %>
```

Comment: Oh !! I had the wrong syntax - I had :message instead of @message! Now it posts. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: disregard that…

`/messages/new` is only available to `GET` requests; this is why your `POST` request fails. Try

```
<%= link_to('Contact', new_message_path, :class => 'contact', :method => :get, :remote => true, 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => '#myModal')  %>
```

Comment: I would have been embarrassed if it worked, because I've tried that, but just in case I tried it again - same error. I've also tried ":action => :create" in the form tag, and it also does not work. There should be some way to tell the form or the routes to POST from messages, and not messages/new.

Comment: Also, in the non-modal form, even though the form is on 'messages/new', it correctly finds the POST route. ???

Comment: @DeborahSpeece the form itself is rendered by a GET call to `/messages/new`, but it POSTs to `/messages`.